# Android layout screen resolution problems

Tags: android, layout, screen, resolution

I have almost finished my app for android, the problem is when i test it on multiple screen sizes the layout of items such as padding etc, seems to be incorrect. I don't understand how I am supposed to support all screen sizes, because I have used all 'dp' values for the text and sizes for padding etc. I am using the 'background' as an image which fills the screen, and the background includes the layout of buttons and boxes that will have textviews overlaying them. I have been testing on my HTC desire and I have just noticed this issue. I assumed that it would all be okay seeing as I have been using dp for all measurments etc. Any tips to fix my layouts would be appreciated as my app is pretty much good to go apart from this :(

Comment: Please check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518557/1939564 i'm sure this will help you!!

Comment: Yes check Mohammad Babar solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156752/multiple-screen-resolution/16518557#16518557 . This should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following links very carefully you will get the best way to do:

1. [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
2. [Support for Multiple Screen Resolutions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120211224013/http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Support_for_Multiple_Screen_Resolutions)
3. [Support for additional screen resolutions and densities in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/support-for-additional-screen.html)
4. [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)
5. [MultiResolution - Multiple Resolutions](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html)

Comment: i read through these and each say to use dp...which is what i am using already.