# Multiple screen resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I am developing the app in 320*480. How do make the app to be run in 480*854 screen? When i tried to run in 480*854 screen, the app original design looks like small. Do I want to create separate layouts for each screen in android? If so, please provide me the sample hint to proceed.

Answer (score 8):

I have implemented my own way of **Handling Multiple Screen Resolutions**.

You could certainly avoid this problem by setting `LayoutParams` at run time in terms of **Percentage**

The **Problem** occurs only with `Views/Layouts` that have some constant **width** or **height** lets say `280dp`. **Solution** is quite simple if we programmatically set Layout Params of our `Views/Layouts` in terms of **Percentage** and only use constant **width** or **height** where necessary, elsewhere try to use `match_parent` to fill up empty space or use `weights` and define every `View` relative to other `Views` this will help your layout to look good in almost every screen resolutions

Here is a sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mLayout"
            android:layout_width="280px"
            android:layout_height="300px" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Notice:** I have used **px** for fixed sized layout's **width/height** because in `LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(int width, int height);` the `width` and `height` take value as **pixels**

Here is an example code of setting **width** and **height** in terms of percentage

```
final ViewTreeObserver mLayoutObserver = mLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

    mLayoutObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            int deviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

            int deviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

            float widthInPercentage =  ( (float) 280 / 320 )  * 100;

            float heightInPercentage =  ( (float) 300 / 480 ) * 100;

            int mLayoutWidth = (int) ( (widthInPercentage * deviceWidth) / 100 );

            int mLayoutHeight = (int) ( (heightInPercentage * deviceHeight) / 100 );

            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(mLayoutWidth, mLayoutHeight);

            mLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

Now might be some people are wondering what is happening here

`float widthInPercentage =  ( (float) 280 / 320 )  * 100`

Let me explain **280** is the width of my `LinearLayout` and **320** is the width of my device screen(on which i'm developing), i know currently i'm testing on a device having resolution **320 x 480**, what i'm doing is calculating how much **area** my layout is covering in terms of **percentage** and then

`int mLayoutWidth = (int) ( (widthInPercentage * deviceWidth) / 100 )`

here i'm calculating the new width for my layout according to the screen resolution and by this way your `Views/Layouts` will look exactly the same on every **screen resolution**.

**Conclusion:** If you need to set some constant **width/height** for your `Views/Layouts` always set value in **px** in layout file (i.e xml) and then programmatically set `LayoutParams`.

A Suggestion for **Google Android Engineers**, i guess you guys should seriously think of changing the `dp/dip` units to `percentage`

Comment: Don't you have a lot of possible errors, since this wont work on ALL the android devices for example the ones running on 3-4 API

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal Yes the above solution is tested for **Api 8** and onward.

Answer (score 1):

for that you can make your layout dynamic with reference to available width and Height of the device

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();
```

set your layout in terms of perecentage with reference to avail size

Comment: You can also take a look here:http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: for this your have create seperate drawables for each screen type

Comment: yes i tried something like that. But I am not sure whether this method is correct or not. Since we have to create separate layouts for all the screens available? Here is my code:
                              DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
  ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
  wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
  if (ht == 240 && wt == 320) {
   setContentView(R.layout.timetable_ldpi);
  } else if (ht == 240 && wt == 400) {
  setContentView(R.layout.timetable_ldpi);
  }

Comment: this method will works, it depends on you how you going implement it

Comment: In this method, I have to create the layouts according to the screen densities,only design view has to  change?

Comment: not layout, the view's size will be flexible

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Babar,

I think you should follow the below formula instead of calculating like

```
float widthInPercentage =  ( (float) 280 / 320 )  * 100;
float heightInPercentage =  ( (float) 300 / 480 ) * 100;
int mLayoutWidth = (int) ( (widthInPercentage * deviceWidth) / 100 );
int mLayoutHeight = (int) ( (heightInPercentage * deviceHeight) / 100 );
```

I would suggest like if you take this as follows:

```
int baseWidth=320;
int baseHeight=480;

int mLayoutWidth = (int) ( (280* deviceWidth) / baseWidth);
int mLayoutHeight = (int) ( (300* deviceHeight) / baseHeight);
```

Also this is going to work for Views and not for text-sizes;

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you don't go by the the absolute resolution, but rather focus on the screen density. 
And yes you might need to create different layout to support various densities and screen sizes. In general there are four densities supported by Android (low, medium, high, extra high)

I suggest you read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for Android. I think it will help you achieve what you need to do. It has various sections on Designing alternative layouts and drawables and other useful info related to supporting multiple screen resolutions.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

hi welcome to stack overflow...
From version 1.6 onward, Android supports multiple screen resolutions and densities separated into three classes:

- Small: devices with a screen size smaller than the T-Mobile G1 or Samsung I7500, like the HTC Tattoo
- Normal: devices with a screen size roughly the same as the G1 or I7500.
- Large: devices with a screen size larger than the G1 or I7500 (such as a tablet-style device.)

Developers can control if and how apps appears to devices in each group by using tools introduced in the Android framework APIs and SDK. Details on implementation can be found in the Android Dev Guide article Supporting Multiple Screens. you may refer this link [MultiResolution](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html)
 or may use

```
Display displayparm= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= displayparm.getWidth();
int Height= displayparm.getHeight();
```