# How to resize view objects on Android depending by screen size

Tags: android

I don't understand how to do this. Can someone explain to me how to do that with an example using an ImageView or a simple button?

Comment: yes you can do it with percentage check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518557/1939564

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this in onCreate to get the correct width and height:

```
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }

            width = view.getWidth();
            height = view.getHeight();

            // using the method Alécio mention
            setupOtherViewsThatDependOnWidthAndHeight();

        }
    });
```

The case here is that size and height does not return correct values before screen is done rendering.

Comment: No problemo - happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Layout parameters for this. You can use it like this, passing the **width** and **height** programmatically (100,100 respectively)

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(100,100);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```