# Cant use the %s method for supporting all screens

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, percentage, screen-resolution

Can someone please tell me how can I apply the percentages method([Multiple screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156752/multiple-screen-resolution/16518557#16518557), as suggested by Muhammad Babar) to fragments becouse I am using the method mentioned by Babar but I get an error while running in the emulator that unfortunately the application has stopped.I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

here is my code:

xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contents"
    android:layout_width="320px"
    android:layout_height="456px" >
  <Button
android:id="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_width="60px"

android:layout_height="30px"


android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:background="#3D3D3D"
android:textColor="#FCFCFC"
android:textSize="25px" />

    <EditText
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="235px"
android:ems="10"
android:gravity="top"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:textSize="20px" />

 <Button
android:id="@+id/Button02"
android:layout_width="60px"
android:layout_height="30px"

android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:background="#3D3D3D"
android:textColor="#FCFCFC"
android:textSize="25px" />



   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my fragment class:

```
 import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


   @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);


// Inflate the layout for this fragment
//
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 RelativeLayout mLayoutContents = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView
            .findViewById(R.id.contents);

 final ViewTreeObserver mLayoutObserver = mLayoutContents.getViewTreeObserver();

    mLayoutObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
             RelativeLayout mLayoutContents = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contents);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            int deviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

            int deviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

            float widthInPercentage =  ( (float) 320 / 320 )  * 100;

            float heightInPercentage =  ( (float) 456 / 480 ) * 100;

            int mLayoutWidth = (int) ( (widthInPercentage * deviceWidth) / 100 );

            int mLayoutHeight = (int) ( (heightInPercentage * deviceHeight) / 100 );

            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(mLayoutWidth, mLayoutHeight);

            mLayoutContents.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
  return fragmentView; 
    }}
```

Comment: thats because %s are not supported, you should use property weight, simmilar effect as %.
also, dont use px, use dp for dimensions

Comment: Usually, to lay things out on a percentage basis, you use `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Containers/LinearPercent