# Android: How to set Item ListView height in percentage?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Hi android developers,

I'm newbie in Android development and now I am programming my first Android app.
However, I have one issue which I cannot figure out.

Situation:
I have implemented ListFragment and ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter.
This adapter returns always five items or less, when the user click on the button from fragment.

The question is How can I set item height to 20percent of parent element?
I tried set layout_weight to 20 of layout item with layout_height="0dp" but this not solved my issue.
If set height in percentage not possible, can I get height of parent element and set item height programmatically?

Fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_light"
    tools:context=".Fragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/footer"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        style="@style/footer" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/button.next"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_white"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment class onActivityCreated method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)getActivity();

  ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter (getActivity(), activity.getNextItems(5));
  setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV_order"
            android:text="@+id/txt_order"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"           
            android:textColor="?darkColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV_text"
            android:text="@+id/txt_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtV_order"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:textColor="?darkColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/standard_padding">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_toggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroud="@drawable/toggle"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ItemAdapter class getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

  TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtV_order);
  textView.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));
  textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtV_text);
  textView.setText(item[position].getText());

  ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_toggle);

  //if true - set checked if false - set unchecked
  btn.setChecked(item[position].isChecked());

  onToggleBtnClick(btn, position);

  return rowView;
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

My Util class:

```
public class Utils {

  //get status bar height
  public static int getStatusBarHeight(Activity activity) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
      result = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
  }

  //get action/title bar height
  public static int getActionBarHeight(Activity activity) {
    Rect rect= new Rect();
    Window window= activity.getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int statusBarHeight= rect.top;
    int contentViewTop= window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();

    return contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;
  }

  //get screen height with bars
  public static int getScreenHeight(Activity activity) {

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = size.y;

    return height;
  }

  //get height of layout...
  public static int getLayoutHeight(Activity activity) {
    return getScreenHeight(activity) - getActionBarHeight(activity) - getStatusBarHeight(activity);
  }

}
```

In ItemAdapter class:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

int numberOfItems = 5;
int itemHeight = (int)(Utils.getLayoutHeight(context) / numberOfItems);

rowView.setMinimumHeight(itemHeight);
```

Comment: That's not how layout_weight works. Weight is a ratio based on all other weights. For example, three views with weights 2, 1, 1 respectively would result in the first view's height (or width) being twice that of the second or third. Does that make sense?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518557/1939564

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Set it programatically.
2. Use LinearLayout with weight.

for 2 in xml in linearlayout set the `android:weightsum=10` and `android:layoutweight=8` for listView

[LayoutWeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work) : This is a nice link for you to understand.

Comment: I don't think so, if you understand my question. I cannot use android:weightSum for ListView, which is parent element of the items. Each of item must has 20percent, because I have always 5 items in ListView.
Code please.

Comment: Firstly, we don't provide codes on stackoverflow, you should write your own(it takes time, but it's worth it). Secondly, my answer is still okay. You calculate the [screensize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155559/how-to-get-android-device-screen-size) and in getView set the layout parameters(you can do anything to the view in it). OR use option 2.

Answer (score 0):

In my question post is a my solution to set item height programmaticaly by number of items, which I want in the layout and fill it.