# Android layout for different screen resolution but tablet of same dimension

Tags: android, resolution

I have developed an App intended to work on 10" tablets.
I have made my design tests on three different tablets:

Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (1280*800)
Arnova 10g2 (1024*600)
Arnova 10bg3 (1024*600)

I have made a distinction between layout-large and layout-xlarge

My problem is that 
Galaxy tab uses the layout defined in xlarge
Arnova 10 g2 uses the layout defined in xlarge
Arnova 10 bg3 uses the layout defined in large

As the screen resolutions are different I understand that The Arnova 10bg3 and the Samsung are not using the same layout category.

But I don't understand why the Arnova 10g2 uses the xlarge layout while it has the same screen definition as the other Arnova.

This leads me to the problem that the design for 1280 * 800 is not well applied on the Arnova. What can I do?

Comment: here is an other question that may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382110/android-layout-screen-resolution-problems?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are two `600 * 1024` resolution screens.

So when you want to differentiate your layouts, you must use following method in layout directory creation.

1) low density with extra large screen
`layout-xlarge-ldpi` 
2) medium density with large screen
`layout-large-mdpi`

So, when you want to create specific layout screen for specific resolution, you must go with `layout-<screen-size>-<density>`

[image: Multiple screen support]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried by using layout-xlarge-mdpi and layout-xlarge-ldpi. And I've got two problems : the problem is still there. the second problem is that I can't use something like layout-xlarge-mdpi-land, eclipse refuses it

Comment: If you are using `GINGER BREAD` and earlier API, what i have suggested will be used, otherwise 3.2+ API has different scenario of `layout-sw600dp` means `layout for smallest 600 dp width`, `layout-sw720dp` means `layout for smallest 720 dp width`. You can find more information from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts